# php handle business open and close time

Tags: php

Try to get each store open and close condition, if in operation time echo open, if not echo close.

for example: monday-friday: 11:00 am - 2:00 am (which open to midnight)

here is my code

```
$currentTime = strtotime("01:14 pm");       $rangeStart = strtotime("11:00am");         $rangeEnd = strtotime("tomorrow 02:00 am");
if ($currentTime >= $rangeStart && $currentTime <= $rangeEnd) {
   echo 'in range';         
} else {
        echo 'not in range';        
}
```

this working good, because current time is 01:14 pm afternoon.

so i try to set the current time to 01:14 am midnight, here is the problem.

which will echo not in range, because $currentTime is less than $rangeStart.

this problem alrady bother me for 2 days.....any help please, thanks

Comment: say today is the 04 Jan 2017. $currentTime would be 1am on the 04 Jan 2017. you would need to set $currentTime  to strtotime("tomorrow 01:00 am"); OR you could compare $currentTime to yesterday's opening and closing times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `$currentTime` is less than `$rangeStart`.

If true then increase `$currentTime` by one day.

```
<?php
$currentTime = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime("01:14 am"));      
$rangeStart = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime("11:00 am"));         
$rangeEnd = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime("tomorrow 02:00 am"));

if($currentTime < $rangeStart){
    $currentTime = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime("tomorrow".date('H:i',strtotime($currentTime))));     
}


if ($currentTime >= $rangeStart && $currentTime <= $rangeEnd) {
    echo 'in range';         
} else {

    echo 'not in range';        

}
?>
```

Comment: explain your answer

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam am checking current time if its less than start time am increasing to 1 day

Comment: Add it to answer that will help others just posting code without explanations may lead to confusion.

Comment: let him check this piece of code if working with his all scenarios then i can

Comment: am sure but let him verify all scenarios

Comment: it's working like charm, sorry been late reply, great job thank you :)